# Lua patterns query

Tags: string, lua, lua-patterns

I need to detect a word say **john** from a larger string, say **john is a good man**
So I have this pattern to find the word

```
[j][o][h][n]
```

and use it as follows:

```
local pattern = "[j][o][h][n]"
local str = "john is a good man"
print(str:find(pattern))
```

In order to accept if letters occur multiple times(e.g **jooohn is a good man**), I modify the pattern as

```
[j]+[o]+[h]+[n]+
```

I need to ignore spaces(or other non alphabetic chars) which may occur in between the word(e.g **joh;n is a good man**), so I add  [^a-z]* to each letter and the result pattern is

```
[j]+[^a-z]\*[o]+[^a-z]\*[h]+[^a-z]\*[n]+[^a-z]\*
```

Now this is perfect for a word like "jooh!n is a good man".  But if the **!** symbol occurs within the repetiting letter, the pattern fails. 
For example, in ***jo!ohn is a good man*** the pattern is not detected.
How do I modify my pattern in order to achieve this?

**EDIT**

Example:

```
local str = "jooohn is a good man"
local pattern = "[j]+[^a-z]*[o]+[^a-z]*[h]+[^a-z]*[n]+[^a-z]*"
print(str:find(pattern))
```

this will print 
   `1  7`

But

```
 local str = "joo!ohn is a good man"
 local pattern = "[j]+[^a-z]*[o]+[^a-z]*[h]+[^a-z]*[n]+[^a-z]*"
 print(str:find(pattern))
```

will print only `nil`
I need a pattern which allows me to detect **joo!ohn** in scenario 2

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @lhf   the pattern which I am asking will be used to find the string "john" or a modified variant of "john" from a larget string.. does that make sense? 
I have updated the question as well!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do `"j[j%W]*o[o%W]*h[h%W]*n[n%W]*"`:

```
local str = "joo!ohn is a good man"
local pattern = "j[j%W]*o[o%W]*h[h%W]*n[n%W]*"
print(str:find(pattern))
```

prints `1 8`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! this works! but I have no idea how. Would you mind explaining this a bit Paul?

Comment: ok I figured it.. `The upper cased version of the above reverses the meaning of said (i.e. %A --- represents all non-letters).`
So we look for 0 or more of [a non-alphanumeric character or the same letter]  
thanks a lot Paul!!!

Comment: And since I want only letters(as opposed to alphanumeric), I would replace `%W` by `%A`!

Comment: @SatheeshJM, yes, you figured it out correctly. And the proposed change should work too.